# Exposing Ubuntu localhost to the public and connecting a personal domain to it

Tags: networking, ubuntu, localhost

I've recently acquired an Ubuntu VPS from vultr and I was planning on hosting a small database on it. I am of course able to access it from localhost:port but when it comes to using the actual server's IP address from my computer, the server is not publicly available. I've tried using things like localtunnel and ngrok, but they all only provide their domain and you have to pay for higher bandwidth and custom subdomains.

I've been researching through lots of questions on StackOverflow and other websites but I couldn't find one that would just plainly explain how to expose the localhost to the public without using the popular services I listed below or the ones that apply to ubuntu.

Imagine my VPS' IP Adress is xxx.xx.xxx.xx.x

Everything I want to do is to be able to access this from the internet when I start up my database:

xxx.xx.xxx.xx.x:5000 or even better: just being able to access it without the port, maybe by changing it to 443 (But how should I connect an ssl certificate to it then?)

I then just want to point the domain at that ip so it will be connected :)

If I am wrong or misunderstood in some cases, feel free to comment below as I just want to be able to know more about this topic.

Comment: Is your server directly connected to the internet ? Or is it on a private network behind a NAT? Moreover, database server are often listening only on loopback address (127.0.0.1 or localhost). Could you check the listening address for the database service by using "netstat -lt"

Comment: You have provided little teal information.  What database?  It is not possible with localhost as localhost by definition only reachable locally - but you can access the system on its public facing IP.  Have you adjusted your firewalls? Have you bound your DB to listen on public facing ip? (Does vulture have an additional firewall layer you need to open up).

Comment: Also, exposing a database to the wide onternet without IP restriction is foolhardy.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the comments. My app is too basic to be true, it is just a flask python script connected to an sql database... @S.Brottes here is the screenshot i got from running netstat -lt: https://imgur.com/a/OkH3RdV. I am not able to access the system from its external ip adress and I believe my firewall layer for ports 443, 5000 and 80 is opened up.

Comment: As you can see, your database is running only on localhost (localhost:5000). It should run under the ip address of the machine, or 0.0.0.0 (like ssh service) to be reachable by other machine. You must have a parameter to modify in the configuration file of your database service to specify the binding address. Moreover, as davidgo say in its comment, it could be dangereous to expose database.

Comment: Hi! I'm aware that the database starts on 0.0.0.0 as the screenshot says here: https://imgur.com/a/nNxIa4O however it is still impossible to access it! Do you have any other thoughts?